# How show one single item in a page AngularFire?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I am trying to show only one record in a single page using AngularJs and Firebase. I have been trying using ng-href to show one record but it's not working.

This is the html code

```
<div class='box-footer box-comments' ng-repeat="article in articles">
                                <div class='box-comment'>
                                    <!-- User image -->
                                    <img class='img-circle img-sm' src='img/connections.png' alt='user image'>
                                    <div class='comment-text'>
                                        <span class="username">
                                            {{article.title}}
                                            <span class='text-muted pull-right'>8:03 PM Today</span>
                                        </span><!-- /.username -->
                                        {{article.post}}
                                    <hr class="divider" />
                                    <pre><code class="html">{{article.postCode}}</code></pre>
                                    </div><!-- /.comment-text -->
                                </div><!-- /.box-comment -->

                                <div class='box-body'>
                                    <!-- Social sharing buttons -->
                                    <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs btn-flat'><i class='fa fa-share'></i> Share</button>
                                    <button class='btn btn-default btn-xs btn-flat'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-o-up'></i> Like</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-flat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span></button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-flat"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span></button>
                                    <!--<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-flat" target="_blank" ng-href="#/show/?id={{article.$id}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span></a>-->
                                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-flat" target="_blank" ng-href="#/show/?id={{article.$id}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-share"></span></a>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-flat" ng-click="editPost(article.$id)" data-target="#editModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit weet</button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-flat" ng-click="confirmDelete(article.$id)" data-target="#deleteModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Delete</button>
                                    <span class='pull-right text-muted'>45 likes - 2 comments</span>
                                </div><!-- /.box-body -->
                                <div class="box-footer"><small class="text-primary">Post written by <a><b>{{username}}</b></a> <small><img width="2%" src='img/user-list.png' alt='user image'></small> </small></div>
                            </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
```

This is the controller I am using to show a single item

```
angular.module('myApp.show', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/show', {
    templateUrl: 'showPost/show.html',
    controller: 'showCtrl'
});
}])

.controller('showCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebase', 'CommonProp', '$location',    function ($scope, $firebase, CommonProp, $location) {
//Code
$scope.username = CommonProp.getUser();
//$scope.profile = CommonProp.getUser();
//Create method for uploading profile picture.

if (!$scope.username) {
    $location.path('/home');
}
var firebaseObj = new Firebase("https://crackling-inferno-2072.firebaseio.com/Articles");
var sync = $firebase(firebaseObj.startAt($scope.username).endAt($scope.username));
//var sync = $firebase(firebaseObj.startAt($scope.profile).endAt($scope.profile));


//var sync = $firebase(firebaseObj);

$scope.articles = sync.$asArray();
console.log(sync);

$scope.logout = function () {
    CommonProp.logoutUser();
    location.reload();
}
}]);
```

And this is the code of web where I need to show on item from firebase.

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>   
<div ng-repeat="article in articles">
    <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
    <p>{{article.post}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Would somebody help me out with this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's "not working?" Are you seeing multiple rows or none at all?

Comment: I am trying to show one single record from the Firebase in a new page. I tried with ng-href but it's not working. And certainly I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: I understand that it's not working - that's why I asked what you meant by "not working." Are you seeing nothing at all or more rows than you want? I'm not sure what you're trying to do with console.log(sync), but I'd start by inserting a console.log($scope.articles) there and see what the output is.

Comment: I can see the all the items in one page. But I need to show one record in a single page by clicking a button.

Comment: You're using a *really* outdated version of AngularFire (0.8 by the look of it).  You should strongly consider upgrading to 1.2. There's breaking changes, but the docs have a migration guide. https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/migration-guides.html

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using ng-repeat to list out your line items, so everything is actually working properly. Since you only want one article here, you should just use:

```
<div>
    <h1>{{articles[0].title}}</h1>
    <p>{{articles[0].post}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In the [0], I am supposed there should be the ID of the record I need to show?

Comment: The zero represents the first row in the array. You have to supply the ID somewhere if there's a specific article you want to display.